# WCF, who is calling? IIS self hosted with multiple websites, calling each other

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client, wcf-hosting

I have a WCF service hosted on a website. I have mutliple bindings on the same website. Each website can call the WCF service on another site.

Because of this, the endpoint the client uses is a dynamic address.

**Q:** Is it possible to know what the address the caller is using when it hits the host?

I am looking for something similar to the following without having to send it as a param.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]
```

**Client Example**

```
// The endpoint being called is - 
// http://www.helloworld.com/Services/EchoService.svc for example.  
EchoServiceClient client = new EchoServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IEchoService", GetEndpoint("EchoService"));
litResponse.Text = client.Echo();
client.Close();
```

**Host Example**

```
public class EchoService : IEchoService
{
    public string Echo()
    {
        return "Echo: " + {something like WCF.Caller.EndPoint.Address};
    }
}
```

**Output similar to**

```
Echo: http://www.helloworld.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is:**

```
System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.To
```

**Returns:**

```
http://www.helloworld.com/Services/EchoService.svc
```